# R dataframe convert "list" type columns to chr/int/

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am handed a dataframe that looks like this:

```
a = as.data.frame(cbind(list("BNP Paribas", NULL, "Bano SA", "Unicredit"),
  list(1,2,3,4)))
```

I want to convert it to a frame like this:

```
NAME <- c("BNP Paribas", NA, "Bano SA", "Unicredit")
value <- c(1,2,3,4)
b<- data.frame(NAME,value)
```

Edit: The earlier version of this post contained confusing scnreeshots. I found a way to create the two data structures in question programmatically.

Comment: What is `class(c_67)` ?

Comment: `numeric` while the other one is `data.frame`

Comment: I tried `as.data.frame(c_67)`

Comment: How do you create the data.tables?

Comment: You should provide us more information than just a screenshot to help you. Are you sure `class(c_67)` returns numeric? What is `length(c_67)`? What is `lengths(c_67)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what happened here. In your first example it looks like `c_67` is a nested list of lists of single character elements, while in the latter you seem to have a standard `data.frame`.

I would assume something along the lines of

```
columns <- as.data.frame(lapply(c_67, unlist, recursive = TRUE))
```

would do your job. But if you can query it from somewhere else, that would seem like the better option.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution does not work if there are NULLs in the data. See my updated generic example.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than your prior example. I'll take a minute to check it out

Comment: based on your solution, I came up with: `c <- as.data.frame(sapply(a, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", NA, x)))
a_new <- as.data.frame(lapply(c, unlist, recursive = TRUE))` which seems to work. Feel free to adjust your answer using this, so I can accept.

Comment: That is a lot shorter than my own idea, so just keep doing that. :-) Rather add your own answer and accept that.